# Will current Teams users part of the private alpha be grandfathered in to the current pricing? If so, for how long?

Tags: support, stack-overflow-for-teams

Now that Stack Overflow for Teams has launched (as a paid service), what will happen to teams that are currently part of the private alpha? Will they immediately have to start paying, or will those teams continue to be free? If so, for how long will they be free, before they have to start paying?

What about the Charcoal team? I believe they should be able to maintain their team free of charge, given that they essentially "pay" for it through their massive spam-fighting efforts.

Comment: Am I the only one who is still highly confused as to what Teams are and what their purpose is on this site, despite reading all the threads on meta about it?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ isn't it just a private instance of Stack Overflow, accessible from and merged into the main site (at least as far as notifications go)?

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't know, there have been so many back-and-forths that I've lost track. From my understanding, Teams was sorta like a Stack Overflow version of code wars, with Teams competing with each other for prestige. Now, it sounds more like Channels to me.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ It is Teams. Channels was renamed Teams.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ it’s basically a cheaper version of Stack Overflow Enterprise (which is an instance of SO hosted on your own servers) that SO hosts, designed for smaller teams.

Comment: @JF Thanks, both, for the explanation. Last thing: what of the idea to build a platform for teams to compete against _each other_ and show off their work to the public? Because, IIRC, that was under consideration as well.

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That may be a question for meta.SE?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

We had two different phases of rollout with different payment scenarios, so let me lay those out for you.

**Unpaid Alpha**

Teams who participated in the earliest phase of the product currently get it for free.

They will continue to receive the product for free until June 1st, at which point they will be converted to a special promotional price as a thank you for their assistance throughout the alpha. That pricing is valid for the first year.

We've reached out to the owners of those teams letting them know about next steps to convert them over to paid accounts.

*Note: there are a couple special cases where pricing is free because of the nature of the team - such as an open source community that contributes to the SE Network.*

**Paid Beta**

Teams who participated in the Beta have been paying from the start. Their pricing is locked in for a year.

Comment: "an open source community that contributes to the SE Network"...does the Charcoal team count as one of those?

Comment: @gparyani precisely :) Charcoal gets it for free.

Comment: Also, what is the discounted rate for private alpha users who convert to paid accounts?

Comment: Does SOBotics also count those open source community. I'm not quite sure as Charcoal covers the whole SE network and we (on SOBotics) mainly work here on SO.

Comment: @Filnor SOBotics gets it for free as well!

Comment: Just to clarify; is the free pricing for open source communities that contribute to SE only valid for the first year?

Comment: @Sam it will be forever free in that scenario.

Comment: We appreciated this greatly, thank you Chance! Teams is a great resource and I plan to propose using it within my teams at work.

Comment: @Undo you guys have been great Teams partners and have provided an awesome resource to the community. It's a no-brainer! Glad you're enjoying it.

Comment: Thank you for that @Chance, we'll now try our best to flood your inbox with bug reports. <3

Comment: I wonder if a list of those "forever-free" special cases is publicly available.

Comment: @iBug no documentation on that yet. Currently, inquiries to teams@ are reviewed on a case by case basis.

Comment: @ChanceHeath Uh, I simply meant "Can you tell me how many forever-free teams are there and what are they". Maybe I spoke too formally.